# Roblox Studio: Proximity Prompt Interact

Tags: lua, roblox

I need an instruction or script using proximity promt. When a character uses proximity promt (hold E), he gets a perk, for example, an increase walking speed and/or an increase health points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need an idea of where to start you could think about using the triggered event of the proximity prompt and adding the powerup code inside the function.

```
proximityPrompt.Triggered:connect(function(player)
    --Power Up Code:
    local character = player.Character
    character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 100
end)
```

This is just meant to give you a rough idea of what the code would look like. Max Health would also be found in Humanoid.

Here are some links that might help:
Proximity Prompts:
https://create.roblox.com/docs/building-and-visuals/ui/proximity-prompts
Power Ups:
https://create.roblox.com/docs/education/coding-3/powerups-with-if-statements